# Tx's not getting mined on private network

Tags: transactions, mining, private-blockchain, txpool

I'm running my own private network - I have 3 pending tx in the pool that are still there 6000 blocks later. I have the miner gas threshold at 0. Any idea why the tx's arent getting mined?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming these are the first transactions submitted by the account. If so, your nonce should be starting at 0. The image shows that the first pending transactions with a nonce of 1. Those transactions won't be processed until a transaction with nonce 0 is submitted.

Comment: No, the account nonce. If you've run transactions through MetaMask for an account and then recreated your private network, MetaMask will still have the transaction count cached. Getting MetaMask to sync back up can be problematic. You can try switching networks, but you may even have to reinstall MetaMask. You can also try just using a new account.

Comment: Ya, I realized how dumb of a question that was and deleted it. Not fast enough I guess. Not sure how the nonce got off though. WIll the miner pick tx with lower gas than the miner gas limit if there are no other tx's in the pool? also is there a way to check your nonce?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Txs for the same account must be processed in order (pretty sure you've got that part). If 2 txs show up with the same nonce, then typically the one with the higher gas price will be mined and the other will fail.

Comment: use `eth.getTransactionCount(address)` to get the current nonce.

Comment: In the console you can set a miner gas limit: `miner.setGasPrice()` im wondering if i only have one miner and there were tx's in the pool that were under gas limit, would the miner ever mine them?

Comment: If the submitted transactions have a gas PRICE (not limit) lower than the value set in `miner.setGasPrice`, then yes, those will be ignored. But, you said you set the miner's gas price to 0, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. The miner defaults much higher than 0 so I might need to adjust that somewhere.